# What are the permissions needed for GA exports to BigQuery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'd like to set up a GA export to BigQuery. I'm following the steps as described [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092). In step 2.5, it states:

> Add the service account to your project.
>
> Add analytics-processing-dev@system.gserviceaccount.com as a member of
>   the project, and ensure that permission at the project level is set to
>   Editor (as opposed to BigQuery Data Editor). Editor permission is
>   required in order to export data from Analytics to BigQuery.

However, I'm reluctant to provide such elevated permissions ("project editor" will allow **full** access to **all** resources in my project) on my project.

**Why does the GA export need such elevated permissions in order to just talk to BigQuery, and is there a way to provide minimum permissions to the service account instead?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect the documentation is outdated, and hasn't been kept up to date with changes to BigQuery's IAM and permissions.

You do **not** need to give `"Project Editor"` access to the service account. And in fact, providing such elevated security permission on a generic service account is violating the principle of least privileges.

Instead, create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) within IAM with the following minimum BigQuery permissions for the export to work. This way, it can only interact with BigQuery in your project:

1. `bigquery.datasets.create` (allows GA to create the dataset for export)
2. `bigquery.jobs.create` (allows GA to run load jobs)
3. `bigquery.tables.create` (allow GA to create the tables)
4. `bigquery.tables.delete` (allows GA to delete intraday tables)

[image]

Comment: 3 years on.. doc still seems outdated :=)